# react-hls-player streaming video

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-hls-player in my project . this is my sample code

```
 const playerRef = useRef();
    return (
      <ReactHlsPlayer
          playerRef={playerRef}
          src="http://sample.vodobox.com/planete_interdite/planete_interdite_alternate.m3u8"
          autoPlay={false}
          controls={true}
          width="100%"
          height="auto"
         
      />
  );
```

i want to know is there any way to change hls video quality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-hls-player` uses `hls.js` under the hood. You can get the HLS player instance by using [ref](https://github.com/devcshort/react-hls#using-playerref).

You can change the level(video quality) by setting `currentLevel` in `hls.js`

See the [documentation](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#hlscurrentlevel) for more information.

**Update:**

It seems like `react-hls-player` does not expose `hls` instance. You can see from [source code](https://github.com/devcshort/react-hls/blob/739acb5b4d28be3a9a3a540669fc50e6c55a0ed1/src/index.tsx#L86) that `playerRef` is a reference to `video` tag. So you cannot access `hls` API.

You can do two things:

1. Patch the package and expose `hls` instance.
2. Write your own React component.

Comment: i tried this but you know what playerRef.current.currentLevel is undefined

Comment: I updated my answer. You cannot access `hls` instance.

Comment: The `react-hls-player@3.0.7` has  a peer dependency of  `react@"^16.13.1`. Can't use for latest react 18.

Comment: You probably could copy the code into your codebase and use it. I have not used `react-hls-player` ever but I don't think it would break if you used it with react v17 or 18. Another library which renders a react component that uses `hls.js` under the hood  is [react-player](https://github.com/cookpete/react-player) which you can use.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gumlet/react-hls-player), it supports a callback for the HLS Player object as soon as it becomes available in the component. You can then use this HLS object to change the video quality by setting the `currentLevel` the documentation is available [here](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#hlscurrentlevel)

Comment: Is this your own package? You must disclose this when posting an answer

Comment: @Harrison Yes, I am one of the contributors on this package